# Find the smallest positive integer statisfying two conditions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

> Find the smallest positive integer satisfying both of the following requirements: 
>   $(a)$ Its units digit is $6$ 
>   $(b)$ If the units digit $6$ is moved before the first digit, the new number is $4$ times the original number.

Well obviously the units digit of the answer is $6$, but I don't know how to proceed. The only explanation I received was "Just work out the digits one by one, starting from the right," which to me is ambiguous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start with the units digit being $6$.  Then you know that the number is of the form 
$$
\ast\ast\ast\ast\cdots\ast\ast6.
$$
We know that
$$
6\ast\ast\ast\ast\cdots\ast\ast
$$
should be $4$ times the original.  Since $6\cdot 4=24$, the units digit of this new number is $4$.  Therefore, this number is of the form
$$
6\ast\ast\ast\ast\cdots\ast4.
$$
Hence, the original number is of the form 
$$
\ast\ast\ast\ast\cdots\ast46.
$$
Now, keep going like this.

I got an answer of $153846$.

Comment: I was just trying this. Is there a way to show that this process will terminate? Other than actually doing it and finding that it does, I mean.

Comment: No, I don't think that it necessarily terminates (although, it would be an unfair question if it didn't)

Comment: This will always terminate if the problem has a solution.  It is based on the repetition of the decimal expansion.  If the problem does not have a solution (shame on the setter) it will loop without coming to a solution which indicates that fact.

Comment: Oh, so that's what the explanation meant... btw your answer is correct

Comment: One should be able to use @RossMillikan 's answer (perhaps with Hensel lifting) to test for termination too.

Comment: Actually I still don't know how to solve this... can you show how to obtain the $8$?

Comment: You know that the last two digits are $46$, multiplying that by $4$ gives that the last two digits of $4$ times the original is $84$.  Moving the $6$ back to the units place means that the last three digits are $846$.  Continue...

Answer (score 5):

Hint:  the formal way:  write your original number as $10a+6$ and let $a$ have $n$ digits.  Then $4(10a+6)=6\cdot 10^n+a$  Solve this for $a$ and you will get a fraction.  Find the smallest $n$ that makes the fraction a whole number.

Comment: Is there a formula or rule for this?

Comment: If you did what I suggested you would see the denominator is $39=3\cdot 13$  The repeat of the decimal $1/39$ is $6$ places long because $39$ divides into $999\ 999$ which tells you the number you want is six digits long.

Answer (score 1):

The hint means just what it says. Your know that your number is $\text{[some digits]}6$, and you should go ahead and start multiplying it by $4$ just as you would do multiplication of a long number by a single-digit number on paper by hand:
$$\text{[some digits]}6\cdot4=6\text{[same digits]}.$$
First of all, since $6\cdot4=24$, the last digit of the product is $4$. So it's the last of unknown digits, and now you have
$$\text{[some digits]}46\cdot4=6\text{[same digits]}4.$$
Keep on going until you get a $6$ in the beginning of the product, indicating that you're done.